# Shell Script Stops after SQL code

Tags: sql, sh

my code is always stopping after ENDOFSQL; 
How to resolve this Problem and print the last echo?

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus db/pass << ENDOFSQL

@script.sql

exit;   
ENDOFSQL;

echo -e "text"
```

Comment: code or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

You must remove the semicolon `;` at the end of `ENDOFSQL;`. Otherwise, your here document extends until the end of file and `ENDOFSQL;` and `echo` is part of the here document

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus db/pass << ENDOFSQL

@script.sql

exit;   
ENDOFSQL

echo -e "text"
```

See [`Here Documents`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) for details

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> <<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line **containing only word** (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.

Comment: It is working without the semicolon ; at the end of ENDOFSQL !!! 
Thanks all for help : )

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus db/pass @script.sql
echo -e "text"
```

Make sure you have the `exit` at the end of your .sql file.